# select month by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

i need to write a query that print a daily statistics of calls. 
my calls table looks like this:

```
user    date
1       3/6/2011
1       15/7/2011
```

my results should be like this:

```
date               count

1/6/2011            0
2/6/2011            0
3/6/2011            1
...
30/6/2011           0
```

how can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT month.date, count(userid)
FROM generate_series(DATE '2011-06-01', DATE '2011-06-30', '1 day') month
LEFT JOIN calls ON (month.date = calls.date)
GROUP BY month.date
ORDER BY month.date ASC;
```

More general solution (so you can specify month and year as parameter):

```
SELECT month.date, count(userid)
FROM generate_series(DATE '2011-06-01', DATE '2011-06-01' + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', '1 day') month
LEFT JOIN calls c ON (month.date = c.date)
GROUP BY month.date
ORDER BY month.date ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [generate_series(start, stop, step interval)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to create a list to join.

Comment: @Rami: The fact you know to use a `LEFT JOIN` suggests you're only interested in someone doing the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a group by you are looking for?

```
select date, count(*) from tablename
group by date 
order by date desc
```

Comment: That won't display values for missing dates

Comment: i need to join my table with generate_series(start, stop, step interval)